# C++ design related question

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Here is the question's plot: suppose I have some abstract classes for objects, let's call it `Object`. It's definition would include 2D position and dimensions. Let it also have some `virtual void Render(Backend& backend) const = 0` method used for rendering.

Now I specialize my inheritance tree and add `Rectangle` and `Ellipse` class. Guess they won't have their own properties, but they will have their own `virtual void Render` method. Let's say I implemented these methods, so that `Render` for `Rectangle` actually draws some rectangle, and the same for ellipse.

Now, I add some object called `Plane`, which is defined as `class Plane : public Rectangle` and has a private member of `std::vector<Object*> plane_objects;`

Right after that I add a method to add some object to my plane.

***And here comes the question.*** If I design this method as `void AddObject(Object& object)` I would face trouble like I won't be able to call virtual functions, because I would have to do something like `plane_objects.push_back(new Object(object));` and this should be `push_back(new Rectangle(object))` for rectangles and `new Circle(...)` for circles.

If I implement this method as `void AddObject(Object* object)`, it looks good, but then somewhere else this means making call like `plane.AddObject(new Rectangle(params));` and this is generally a mess because then it's not clear which part of my program should free the allocated memory.

*["when destroying the plane? why? are we sure that calls to `AddObject` were only done as `AddObject(new something`).]*

*I guess the problems caused by using the second approach could be solved using smart pointers, but I am sure there have to be something better.*

***Any ideas?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **actual problem seems to be managing the objects' lifetimes**. Four possibilities that come to mind are:

1. Your container (i.e. `Plane`) assumes ownership of all contained objects and therefore `delete`s them once it's itself destroyed.
2. Your container (`Plane`) does not assume ownership and whoever added objects to your container will be responsible for destroying them.
3. The lifetime of your objects is managed automatically.
4. You circumvent the problem by providing the container with a clone of the actual object. The container manages a copy of the object, and the caller manages the original object.

What you currently have seems like approach #4. By doing:

```
plane_objects.push_back(new Object(object));
```

you insert a copy of the object into the container. Therefore the problem sort of disappears. Ask yourself whether this is really what you want, or if one of the above choices would be more suitable.

---

Options #1 and #2 are easy to implement, because they define a contract that your implementation simply has to follow. Option #3 would call for e.g. smart pointers, or some other solution involving reference counting.

**If you want to keep following the approach of option #4,** you could e.g. extend your `Object` class with a `clone` method, so that it returns the right type of object. This would get rid of the incorrect `new Object(...)`.

```
class Object
{
    public:
        virtual Object* clone() const = 0;
        ...
};

...

Object* Rectangle::clone() const
{
    return new Rectangle(*this);  // e.g. use copy c'tor to return a clone
}
```

---

***P.S.:** Note how the STL containers seem to deal with this issue: Let's say you declare a `vector<Foo>`. This vector will contain copies of the objects inserted into it (option #4 in my answer). However, if you declare the collection as `vector<Foo*>`, it will contain references to the original objects, but it will not manage their lifetime (option #2 in my answer).*

Answer (score 3):

Use a smart pointer like `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::intrusive_ptr`.

Why do you assume there is something better than using a smart pointer?  Storing raw pointers in a container generally ends in tears if you don't take extraordinary steps to ensure exception safety in your code.

Comment: But this doesn't actually answer the question posed, which is one of polymorphic cloning.

Comment: @dash:  The original question was about ownership maintenance, which is what this answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `clone` method to your interface to, well, clone instances of your type hierarchy. Each concrete implementation produces a new instance of that specific class, so all type information is preserved.

```
class Object {
public:
  virtual Object clone() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Object {
public:
  virtual Rectangle clone() { /* create and return an identical Rectangle */ }
};

class Ellipse : public Object {
public:
  virtual Ellipse clone() { /* create and return an identical Ellipse */ }
};

class Plane : public Rectangle {
  std::vector<Object*> plane_objects;
public:
  virtual Plane clone() { /* create and return an identical Plane */ }
  void AddObject(const Object& object) {
    plane_objects.push_back(object.clone());
  }
};
```

This implies that the plane is the owner of all its objects, so it should also destroy them in its destructor. If those objects are accessed only internally, they can be stored with plain pointers - although even then smart pointers make disposal simpler and safer. If they are published, however, it is better to use smart pointers to store them.

Answer (score 1):

> when destroying the plane? why? are we
>   sure that calls to AddObject  were
>   only done as AddObject(new something).

It's impossible to be sure. But *something* has to manage the object lifetimes. You should simply clearly document which thing that is.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out your object identity and ownership semantics:

Is each Object a real identity or does it simply refer to a real entity?  For the former, you cannot use clone() and you need to use reference counting (via boost::shared_ptr) or pass by reference if the owner of the instance is guaranteed to outlive the references to it.  For the latter, clone() might make more sense and you can safely ignore ownership issues.

In general you should avoid passing naked pointers around and use boost::shared_ptr instead or references.